# pgffor `foreach` loop over databib macro-generated list

Tags: loops, foreach, datatool, pgffor

The databib package from the datatool bundle allows one to import BibTeX databases and work with them from within LaTeX. The author field can be accessed as `\DTLbibfield{Author}`, which returns data from the bbl file, where it is stored in the format

```
\DTLnewbibitem {Author}{{von1}{Last1}{jr1}{First1},%
{von2}{Last2}{jr2}{First2}}%
```

What I see in my pdf output is `von1Last1jr1First1,von2Last2jr2First2`.

What I would like to do is loop over the comma-separated list.

My first problem is that I do not know exactly what `\DTLbibfield{Author}` returns. First, I assumed `{von1}{Last1}{jr1}{First1},{von2}{Last2}{jr2}{First2}`, but then when trying to loop over this list using `\foreach` from the pgffor package, it sees it as just a single value.

A minimal example illustrating the problem:

```
\begin{filecontents}{data.bib}
@inproceedings{test,
  Author = {Author One and Auteur Twee},
  Title = {An loopy approach to author list iteration},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{databib,pgffor}
  \newcommand{\Authors}{\DTLbibfield{Author}}
\begin{document}
  % GET DATA OUT OF BIBFILE INTO DB
  \nocite{*}
  \DTLloadbbl{data}{data.bib}

  % LOOP OVER ENTRIES
  \DTLforeachbibentry*{data}{
    \Authors\\
    % LOOP OVER AUTHORS IN ENTRY
    \foreach \Author in \Authors {\Author\ *** }
      % seen as one-item list instead of two-item list
  }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that your usage of `\providecommand` is wrong. Moreover `\Authors` will expand to `\DTLbibfield{Author}`, which is certainly not a comma separated list. You have to use `\DTLbibfieldlet\Authors{Author}`, instead of `\providecommand{\Authors}{\DTLbibfield{Author}}`

Comment: Fixed the wrong usage of `\providecommand` (first sentence of comment). The rest of your comment answers the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `\providecommand` is wrong in any case. Even if it worked, `\Authors` would expand to `\DTLbibfield{Author}`, which is not a comma separated list good for `\foreach`, so the only item is processed as a unit.

You should use `\DTLbibfieldlet` instead:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{test,
  Author = {Author One and Auteur Twee},
  Title = {An loopy approach to author list iteration},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{databib,pgffor}

\begin{document}

% GET DATA OUT OF BIBFILE INTO DB
\nocite{*}
\DTLloadbbl{data}{\jobname.bib}

% LOOP OVER ENTRIES
\DTLforeachbibentry{data}{%
  \DTLbibfieldlet\Authors{Author}%
  % LOOP OVER AUTHORS IN ENTRY
  \foreach \Author in \Authors {\Author\ *** }%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]